# Ignore margin for hover in CSS

Tags: css, hover

I have made a little pop up when I hover over a square but I want to go to this popup even with an existing margin.

Here is a snippet with my HTML and CSS code:

```css
.vertical {
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: solid lightgrey;
    position: relative;
}

.frame {
    height: 100%;
}

.st {
    height: 250px;
}

.info {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 120%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: solid black 1px;
    color: white;
}

.vertical:hover .info {
    visibility: visible;
}

.arrow {
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent rgba(2, 0, 0, 0.75) transparent transparent;
    top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical">
   <div class="frame"></div>
   <div class="info">
      <div class="header">
         <div class="name">Hover</div>
      </div>
      <div class="st"></div>
      <div class="arrow"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is an example (if you don't follow the arrow the popup will close):

https://jsfiddle.net/bpez64fr/

I want to ignore the margin and allow the user to go to the popup and make it work as if there was no margin

Comment: May I please request an upvote to my answer, below. You left a comment below the answer saying that the answer could be a good solution in your case, and yet the answer is downvoted (by an unknown user) which makes it appear that there is something wrong with the answer. An upvote from you would offset that downvote. Your call. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My strategy would be to put the element to be shown on hover at `left:100%` so that there's no gap for the cursor to "fall in". You can then use `padding` on this element to create the visual whitespace between the main element and the hover element, and put the element's content in an inner element `.info-inner` in my example. Note that `.info-inner` must be `position:relative` for the positioning of the `.arrow` to work.

Let me know if this works for you.

```css
.vertical {
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: solid lightgrey;
    position: relative;
}

.frame {
    height: 100%;
}

.st {
    height: 250px;
}

.info {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.info-inner {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: solid black 1px;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
}

.vertical:hover .info {
    visibility: visible;
}

.arrow {
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent rgba(2, 0, 0, 0.75) transparent transparent;
    top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical">
   <div class="frame"></div>
   <div class="info">
      <div class="info-inner">
        <div class="header">
           <div class="name">Hover</div>
        </div>
        <div class="st"></div>
        <div class="arrow"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this but here is one example.
It simple positions the element next to the previous one without a gap.

```css
.vertical {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 3px solid lightgrey;
  position: relative;
}

.infoWrap {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: 100%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.2s;
}

.info {
  position: relative;
  background: #eee;
  border: solid #aaa 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #666;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 53px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.vertical:hover .infoWrap {
  opacity: 1;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent #aaa transparent transparent;
  top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical">

  <div class="infoWrap">
    <div class="info">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="name">Hover</div>
      </div>
      <div class="arrow"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the css transitions property to delay the invisibility of the element.

Example:

```
.info{ transition: visibility 2s ease-out;}
```

[<kbd>Updated jsFiddle</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/4n10kwra/)

In this latter example, I increased the distance to the pop-up to improve the demo:

[<kbd>UPDATED Updated jsFiddle</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/4n10kwra/1/)

CSS transitions allow you to delay the advent/removal of a css modification to the DOM, giving the user time to slide the mouse from the box to the pop-up.

References:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition-delay/

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-delay.asp

Comment: How it would help to move mouse over empty space? I can hover on element and only after 2h move my mouse to `.info` element.

Comment: This seems more like a workaround to the problem than the actual solution.

Comment: @Justinas You can move the mouse immediately - there is no delay requirement on the part of the user. The delay applies to the beginning of the visibility transition. The transition delay tells the css to hold-off on making the pop-up invisible for `1s` (or whatever is specified), giving the user ample time to slide the mouse over the gap before the pop-up would be hidden. It's simple, elegant, works as intended, and is a valid solution.

Comment: In my case this solution would be working I just need the user to have time to reach the pop up so thanks you

Comment: @ZeyukanIch' Note that you can assign the amount of delay desired beforer the transition starts (i.e. before the pop-up is hidden) -- it can be `2s` (2 seconds), `5s`, `0.5s`, `0.25s` - whatever you think best. Rather than poking and prodding your HTML scaffolding with margins and padding, a css transition seems to me to be an elegant solution. Your call, just saying...

Comment: In my opinion, the accepted answer seems more appropriate than an arbitrarily-timed transition. This is a clever way around the problem, but it most definitely is a workaround.